# Flutter TextPainter shows scrollbar in CustomPainter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

**Make sure you read the update**

I have a CustomPainter that shows only 2 elements inside it an icon and a text. the problem is that sometimes the text drawn by text-painter shows a scrollbar underneath in web version of the app.
[image]

I'm guessing it only happens when the first line of the text has a long width as long as the maximum with it was given when calling

**Code of `CustomPainter` and in which widget it is used**

```dart
class _AddressItem extends StatelessWidget {
  static const addressTextStyle = TextStyle(
    fontSize: 14,
    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
    package: 'design_system',
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
  );

  const _AddressItem({
    Key? key,
    required this.address,
    required this.icon,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final IconData icon;
  final String address;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final cityTheme = CityTheme.of(context);

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6),
      child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
        final maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth - 10;
        return CustomPaint(
          painter: _AddressItemPainter(
            icon: icon,
            address: address,
            iconColor: cityTheme.colors.primary,
            addressTextStyle: addressTextStyle.copyWith(color: cityTheme.colors.onBackground),
          ),
          size: Size(maxWidth, _textSize(address, addressTextStyle, maxWidth).height),
        );
      }),
    );
  }

  Size _textSize(String text, TextStyle style, double maxWidth) {
    final TextPainter tp =
        TextPainter(text: TextSpan(text: text, style: style), maxLines: 2, textDirection: TextDirection.ltr)
          ..layout(maxWidth: maxWidth - (_AddressItemPainter._iconAndTextSpace + 10));
    return tp.size;
  }
}
```

```dart
class _AddressItemPainter extends CustomPainter with EquatableMixin {
  final IconData icon;
  final Color iconColor;
  final String address;
  final TextStyle addressTextStyle;

  static const _iconAndTextSpace = 24.0;

  _AddressItemPainter({
    required this.icon,
    required this.address,
    required this.iconColor,
    required this.addressTextStyle,
  });

  final tp = TextPainter(
    textAlign: TextAlign.start,
    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
  );

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    tp.text = TextSpan(
      text: String.fromCharCode(icon.codePoint),
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 18,
        fontFamily: icon.fontFamily,
        package: icon.fontPackage,
        color: iconColor,
      ),
    );
    tp.layout();
    tp.paint(canvas, Offset(0, 2));

    tp.text = TextSpan(
      text: address,
      style: addressTextStyle,
    );
    tp.maxLines = 2;
    tp.ellipsis = ' ...';
    localLog.i('###### ${size.width}');
    tp.layout(maxWidth: size.width - (_iconAndTextSpace + 10));
    localLog.v('############### PAINTER address item SIZE ${tp.size}');
    tp.paint(canvas, Offset(_iconAndTextSpace, 0));
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant _AddressItemPainter oldDelegate) => this != oldDelegate;

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [icon, iconColor, address, addressTextStyle];
}
```

**UPDATE :**

I got tired and used a widget instead only for web but the result were the same. then i found out the problem will go away if I remove `maxLines` property from the `Text` widget. but then you can't ellipsize the text

```dart
    if (kIsWeb) {
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 3.0),
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(0, 4),
              child: Icon(icon, size: 18, color: cityTheme.colors.primary),
            ),
            Gap.width(12),
            Expanded(child: Text(address, overflow: TextOverflow.visible)),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
```

Comment: Have you been able to find a workaround? I have the same issue